# HAProxy 1.5: Using replace-header to set SameSite=None does not change cookie header

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, haproxy, samesite

I'm currently stuck using HAProxy 1.5.18 and will not be able to upgrade for the foreseeable future.  As such, I'm trying to use replace-header to add SameSite=None to the cookie set in the backend.  When I read up on replace-header in https://github.com/joyent/haproxy-1.5/blob/master/doc/configuration.txt, it seemed to indicate that I can use it to manipulate the header:

```
http-response replace-header Set-Cookie (C=[^;]*);(.*) \1;ip=%bi;\2
```

To test whether or not this syntax will work, I've setup my backend like so:

```
backend servers-testapp
  balance leastconn
  cookie HELLOWORLD insert 
  http-response replace-value Set-Cookie (HELLOWORLD=[^;]*);(.*) \1;SameSite=None;\2
  server localhost.intranet.com 127.0.0.1:9000 cookie HELLOWORLD
```

However, the response header does not show any change whatsoever:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Date: Mon, 04 Jan 2021 19:54:46 GMT
Content-Length: 2
Set-Cookie: HELLOWORLD=HELLOWORLD; path=/
```

I expect to see some kind of change to the Set-Cookie line, like the SameSite parameter being between HELLOWORLD and path.  What am I missing, if anything?

Answer (score 0):

`http-response replace-value` replaces values in the HTTP response from your backend server. Your backend server did not set the HELLOWORLD cookie, so it does not exist in that response to replace.